# Flink in local execution

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to know how run flink table api in local execution mode. Just a java program and run it using intelleji no need to task manager and job manager and so on .

Answer (score 1):

If your dependencies and JDK are OK you should be able to run Flink program in IntelliJ. Often you need to select an option "Add dependencies with provided scope to classpath" in Run/Debug configuration [image]